# Getting File from Perforce

Tags: perforce, cvs

I have locally remove file from location using rm -rf . when I am trying p4 sync  filename But I am not getting file name and getting message that file is update. I used to run similar command in cvs for getting file **cvs update filename**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/sync.html.

The relevant parts are as follows.

```
Syntax
    p4 [g-opts] sync [-f] [-L] [-k] [-n] [-q] [-m max] [file[revRange]...]
    p4 [g-opts] sync [-L] [-n] [-q] [-s] [-m max] [file[revRange]...]
    p4 [g-opts] sync [-L] [-n] [-p] [-q] [-m max] [file[revRange]...]
```

The flag you want is as follows.

```
-f
    Force the sync. Perforce performs the sync even if the client
    workspace already has the file at the specified revision. If
    the file is writable, it is overwritten.

    This flag does not affect open files, but it does override the
    noclobber client option.
```